# Are there other languages, besides English, where the indefinite (or definite) article varies based on sound?

Tags: list-of-languages, articles, indefinite-article

I was talking today with an English co-worker about whether he says "an H-1B visa" or "a H-1B visa", which hinges on whether one says "aitch" or "haitch" for the letter H.

And I noticed that unlike other languages such as German or French or Romanian that change the indefinite article based on things like gender or case, in English we change the indefinite article based on the *sound* of the following word.

Are there other languages that change the indefinite or definite article based on what the following word *sounds* like?

Comment: In French, the pronunciation (but not the spelling) of the masculine indefinite article *un* depends on the beginning of the following word, it is pronounced like *une* before a vowel. The definite article is shortened to *l'* before vowels. There are also unwritten pronunciation differences for the plural *les*.

Comment: Articles, being short, unstressed, and extremely common, are subject to lenition, contraction, reduction, and deletion in every language, including sharing segments, like _a napron_ and _an orange_. In every language that has them. That goes, btw, for other short, unstressed, extremely common grammatical particles.

Comment: @jknappen, French *un* (like at least some other words ending in a nasal vowel) grows a consonant before vowels, but its own vowel does not change.

Comment: Is there a language with articles where this does *not* happen?  I can't think of one.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Romanian is an example of one that doesn't change article based on the sound of the following word.  (Though this only applies to indefinite articles, as they're the ones that precede their word; definite articles are appended to the word in Romanian.)  Greek is another example.

Comment: @Kyralessa Definite articles count.  Sound changes that are not reflected in writing count.

Answer (score 13):

In Italian, both the indefinite and the definite article change in spelling and pronunciation depending on the following sound, in the masculine gender.

Before vowels, the masculine indefinite article is *un* and the definite article is *l'* ([elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) of *lo*):

- *un albero* (a tree), *l'albero* (the tree)

Before single consonants or consonants followed by semivowels or liquids, the masculine indefinite article is *un* but the definite article is *il*, and this includes the affricate consonants /t͡ʃ/ (spelled 'c' before 'i' or 'e') and /d͡ʒ/ (spelled 'g' before 'i' or 'e'):

- *un ramo* (a branch), *il ramo* (the branch)
- *un fiore* (a flower), *il fiore* (the flower)
- *un treno* (a train), *il treno* (the train)
- *un cielo* (a sky), *il cielo* (the sky)
- *un gioco* (a game), *il gioco* (the game)

Before double consonants (generally 's' followed by a consonant, but other combinations arise in loanwords, especially of Greek origin, including with the double consonant 'x'), and before 'z' which is pronounced as the affricate /t͡s/ or /d͡z/, the masculine indefinite article is *uno* and the definite article is *lo*:

- *uno spazio* (a space), *lo spazio* (the space)
- *uno psicologo* (a psychologist), *lo psicologo* (the psychologist)
- *uno xilofono* (a xylophone), *lo xilofono* (the xylophone)
- *uno zaino* (a backpack), *lo zaino* (the backpack)

Feminine articles are *una* (indefinite) and *la* (definite), but they get elided into *un'* and *l'* before vowels:

- *una foglia* (a leaf), *la foglia* (the leaf)
- *un'ombra* (a shadow), *l'ombra* (the shadow)

These changes are not dependent on the noun the article connects to, but the sound immediately following it, so for example we have:

- *l'albero* (the tree), but *il grande albero* (the big tree)
- *un gioco* (a game), but *uno speciale gioco* (a special game)
- *uno zaino* (a backpack), but *un piccolo zaino* (a small backpack)
- *una foglia* (a leaf), but *un'altra foglia* (another leaf)
- *un'ombra* (a shadow), but *una cupa ombra* (a dark shadow)

These behaviors can be at least partly explained by the [phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics) of Italian: whenever *uno* is used, the phonotactic constraints wouldn't allow for *un* unless the 'n' were dropped entirely; the same issue gives rise to *lo* instead of *il*, which look very different on the surface, but both come from different parts of the Latin word [*illum* or *illud*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illum) (a demonstrative).

The elided forms with an apostrophe can be explained by a tendency to eschew [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)).

Answer (score 10):

A famous example is the Arabic language where the the definite article *al* assimilates to one half of the potential following consonants called [Sun letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_moon_letters) in Arabic grammar. So it is *an-Nil* "the Nile" or *ash-shams* "the sun", but *al-qamar* "the moon".

Answer (score 8):

Catalan masculine singular definite articles.

- /l/ before a vowel sound.
- /el/ before anything else.

What triggers this allomorphy is clearly the *sound*, not the *letter*, as we see **l'interval** /linteɾval/ but **el iode** /eljod/, because of the glide /j/. Also **l'hivern** /liveɾn/ but **el hiat** /eljat/.

I think it is pretty common to "change the indefinite or definite article (*that's called allomorphy*) based on what the following word sounds like" in many languages. Italian has three masculine singular definite articles, /el/, /lo/, and /l/, depending on the following sound. In English, the definite article *the* is pronounced /ðə/ or /ðiː/, sometimes even /ðɪ/.

Maybe the point of interest for you comes from the arbitrary insertion/dropping of /h/, not from the allomorphy.

Answer (score 8):

Quite similarly to Italian (see @LjL very complete answer) and a few other Romance languages, French does this for indefinite and definite articles, but not really the same way English does, in the sense that what we call "Liaison" is very common, though it rarely changes the writing of the articles.

Indefinite articles:

- **Un** verre /**œ̃** vɛʁ/ (**a** glass)
- **Un** arbre /**œ̃.n**‿aʁbʁ/ (**a** tree)

Both mean "**a**" but the second one will have its N pronounced as a "transition" letter between the /œ̃/ and the /a/ to avoid hiatus. The writing is unchanged, though.

A similar process happens with the definite article:

- **Le** verre /**lə** vɛʁ/ (**the** glass)
- **L**'arbre /**l**‿aʁbʁ/ (**the** tree)

Here, "**le**" becomes "**l'**", again to avoid hiatus, but this time the writing changes to reflect the absence of the E.

I've only written a few examples, but this process also happens for a plethora of other articles, in a similar fashion.

Basically, it happens, but the writing only gets modified if a sound disappears completely because of the change.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the famous examples in Europe and the Mediterranean have been mentioned, but we should add the languages where the definite article is simply a suffix, for example the core languages of the Balkan Sprachbund, like Albanian and Romanian, and Armenian, which works very much like they do in this regard.

Turkish does not really have an article but objects are marked for definiteness with a suffix.  In that case the connector varies but also the vowel, because of vowel harmony.  So *-u*, *-yu*, *-i*... are all realisations of the same morpheme, and it varies according to a vowel that need not even be directly adjacent.

Answer (score 4):

Yiddish has exactly the same indefinite article system as English.

a talmed = a student

an epfl = an apple

Comment: Yes, though in Yiddish _an_ is pronounced /an/, whereas in English it's pronounced /æn/ or /ən/. And then there's the fact that some words like _yid_ and _yingl_ are pronounced with silent /y/ but still get /a/ instead of /an/. How many stories begin _Eyner a id ..._?

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, before a feminine noun with stressed initial /a/, the usual feminine singular definite article *la* has an alomorph *el* (which is identical to the masculine singular definite article).

- la vaca (f)
- el agua (f)
- el libro (m)

---

[Why is “agua” masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? “El agua” / “Las aguas”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la/25868#25868) (Spanish SE)