# Besides English, "a" and "an". which other language uses separate articles before vowels?

Tags: vowels, consonants, articles, assimilation

In English, "a" changes to "an" before a vowel or a silent "h". Is there any other language where the article changes its form depending on whether it precedes a consonant sound or a vowel sound?

I have found [another similar question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30888/are-there-other-languages-besides-english-where-the-indefinite-or-definite-a) but that is a more general version of the question asking:

> Are there other languages that change the indefinite or definite article based on what the following word sounds like?

Here, I only want to know which languages change articles according to vowels and consonants?

Comment: Please don't edit an existing question to change it into a totally different question.

Comment: Sure, try French for starters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yiddish shows an exact parallel to the English indefinite article.

The indefinite article is אַן *an* before a vowel and אַ *a* before a vowel.

Yiddish is a West Germanic language like English, but seeing as both languages have closer relatives without this alternation this must be a parallel development rather than shared inheritance.

Comment: Honestly hard to say.  I wouldn’t be surprised if it were common to all West Germanic to do this in the spoken dialects unless being emphatic.  The thing is that Modern Standard German and Dutch are a bit artificial and relatively new.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer its absence in Old English (and earlier Middle English) and Old High German is the main reason it can't be a shared inheritance. The fact that Frisian and (most) dialects on the Dutch-Low-German-High-German continuum mostly rules out an areal change. The fact most of the Continental West Germanic continuum also generally has glottal stops at the start of all "vowel-initial" words also makes the conditioning environment somewhat tricky

Comment: Yeah true, I use a glottal stop in e.g. *e Aff* or *e Esel*

Answer (score 4):

Welsh does a similar thing, though with the definite article rather than the indefinite (which Welsh doesn’t have). In fact, the Welsh article uses a tripartite system:

- Before a vowel sound (including /j/ and /h/, but not /w/), the form is *yr*: *yr ergyd* ‘the shot/blow’, *yr haul* ‘the sun’, *yr iawn* ‘the right/compensation’
- Before a consonant sound (excluding /j/ and /h/), the form is *y*: *y calon* ‘the heart’, *y wawr* ‘the dawn’
- *After* a vowel, the form is always *’r*, regardless of what the following word starts with; this is written with no preceding space: *o’r blaen* ‘before’ (literally ‘from the front [of]’), *mae’r tyndra yn esgyn* ‘the tension is rising’

Answer (score 3):

In Ancient Greek, an article ending in a vowel can merge with a word starting with a vowel, in a phenomenon called "crasis" (κρᾶσις). This doesn't happen before a consonant.

For example, ὁ ἀνήρ > ἁνήρ "the man" (*ho anēr* > *hanēr*), but ὁ πόλεμος "the war" (*ho polemos*).

Answer (score 3):

The Hungarian definite article **a** changes to **az** before a vowel:

> **a** szék “the chair”
> **az** asztal “the table”